# Wrong SVN version number returned in gradle (org.tmatesoft.svn)

Tags: android, svn, android-studio, gradle

I am using the following to get the SVNRevision number.

However, i expected **18, 19, 20, 21**. But it keeps returning **13**, regardless of my latest commits.

Loads of sources say to use the below code though. So why am I not getting the correct numbers.

```
 import org.tmatesoft.svn.core.wc.*

 def getSvnRevision(){
     ISVNOptions options = SVNWCUtil.createDefaultOptions(true);
     SVNClientManager clientManager = SVNClientManager.newInstance(options);
     SVNStatusClient statusClient = clientManager.getStatusClient();
     SVNStatus status = statusClient.doStatus(projectDir, false);
     SVNRevision revision = status.getRevision();
     return  revision.getNumber();
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If its like eclipse, you need to update your project, for the version number locally to increase. Submitting does not seem to update the local files version numbers. Aka, I always commit, then update, so that my project is showing the correct SVN version.

This could be by design too (SVN), not sure.

Comment: Sounds like mixed revisions: http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.basic.in-action.html#svn.basic.in-action.mixedrevs

Comment: @IvanJovović An interesting read and makes sense from the explanation. But it seems to exclude the concept of Having to update before committing? I am always forced to update if my local copy is out of date. So in theory when you commit, everything should be up to date. aka latest revision. Still a bit confused myself about it lol. It is definitely `mixed versions` though, thanks for the info :)!!! Just not sure where forced updates fits in